# Call PHP SOAP web service from JQuery (Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, soap

I have a PHP SOAP web service acting as a relay to call cross domain web services.  The problem I'm having is calling my local PHP web service methods from JavaScript (using JQuery/Ajax).  I want to call a specific method in my web service; e.g. "LoginToAccount";

I'm NOT interested in appending params in the url and then figuring out which method to call...  This is very straight forward in .NET (mywebservice.asmx/LoginToAccount") but can't figure it out how to get this to work in PHP.

I continually get a "500 Internal Server Error" of "Bad Request":
Bad Request

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

function LoginToAccount($email, $passCodeHash) { 
    //...code calling cross-domain web services
    return $jsonEncodedResponse;
  }


function CreateAccount($email, $passCodeHash){
    //...code calling cross-domain web services
    return $jsonEncodedResponse;
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'  => "http://www.myurl/webservices/"));

$server->addFunction('LoginToAccount');
$server->addFunction('CreateAccount');
$server->handle();
?>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpRelay.php/LoginToAccount",
        data: "{email : 'myEmail@email.com', passCodeHash: '12345'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: succeeded,
        error: queryError
    });
}

function succeeded(data, textStatus, request) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data.d);

}

function queryError(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(request.responseText, textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}
```

This is all on the same domain.  Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, the built-in soap-server can only handle XML, not json, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

instead of of using php soapserver you can replace it with the following code:

```
echo $data = (function_exists($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) ? json_encode(array('d'=>$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'](file_get_contents('php://input')))) : 'error: function does not exists';
```

what it does is use the query_string as the function name. it first check if the function exists, if not the error is printed, but if et exists it calls the function with the posted data as criteria, in string format. and in the end, the returned data from the function is printed as a json array with the result set as d.

so your javascript should be as follows (note the url call should be with ? instead of / before the function):

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpRelay.php?LoginToAccount",
        data: "{email : 'myEmail@email.com', passCodeHash: '12345'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: succeeded,
        error: queryError
    });
}

function succeeded(data, textStatus, request) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data.d);

}

function queryError(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(request.responseText, textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}
```

hope this can help you! I know it is a bit late to post this, but i posted it if there is anybody else that needed something like this! I needed it and could not any solution like this, so i had to make the solution myself.

cheers
c_bb

Answer (score 1):

I have tried SOAP PHP server with ajax client and found working code

First Download nusoap library from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

then create **server.php**

```
<?php
//call library 
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 

// Define the TriangleArea method as a PHP function 
function TriangleArea($b, $h) { return 'The triangle area is: ' .(($b*$h)/2); } 
// Define the RectangleArea method as a PHP function 
function RectangleArea($L, $l) { return 'The rectangle area is: ' .($L*$l); }
// create the function 
function get_message($your_name) 
{ 
if(!$your_name){ 
return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!'); 
} 
$result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP"; 
return $result; 
}


//using soap_server to create server object 
$server = new soap_server; 

// Initialize WSDL support 
$server->configureWSDL('mathwsdl', 'urn:mathwsdl'); 


 // Register the TriangleArea method 
   $server->register('TriangleArea',                  // method name
       array('b' => 'xsd:int', 'h' => 'xsd:int'),     // input parameters
       array('area_t' => 'xsd:string'),               // output parameters
       'urn:mathwsdl',                                // namespace
       'urn:mathwsdl#TriangleArea',                   // soapaction
       'rpc',                                         // style
       'encoded',                                     // use
       '1=> : Calculate a triangle area as (b*h)/2'         // documentation
   );

   // Register the RectangleArea method to expose
   $server->register('RectangleArea',                 // method name
       array('L' => 'xsd:int', 'l' => 'xsd:int'),     // input parameters
       array('area_r' => 'xsd:string'),               // output parameters
       'urn:mathwsdl',                                // namespace
       'urn:RectangleAreawsdl#RectangleArea',         // soapaction
       'rpc',                                         // style
       'encoded',                                     // use
       '2=> : Calculate a rectangle area as (L*l)'          // documentation
   );


    // Register the RectangleArea method to expose
   $server->register('get_message',                 // method name
       array('nm' => 'xsd:string'),     // input parameters
       array('area_r' => 'xsd:string'),               // output parameters
       'urn:mathwsdl',                                // namespace
       'urn:get_messagewsdl#get_message',         // soapaction
       'rpc',                                         // style
       'encoded',                                     // use
       '3=> : Print a Message as name'          // documentation
   ); 




if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
// create HTTP listener 
//$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
exit(); 
?>
```

after that create **client.php**

```
<?php 
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 
//Give it value at parameter 
$param = array( 'your_name' => 'Monotosh Roy'); 
//Create object that referer a web services
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost:81/WebServiceSOAP/server.php?wsdl', true); 

 // Check for an error
   $err = $client->getError();
   if ($err) {
      // Display the error
      echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
      // At this point, you know any calls to 
      // this web service's methods will fail
   }


   // Call the TriangleArea SOAP method
   $result = $client->call('TriangleArea', 
      array('b' => 10, 'h' => 15));

   // Check for a fault
   if ($client->fault) {
       echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
       print_r($result);
       echo '</pre>';
   } else {
       // Check for errors
       $err = $client->getError();
       if ($err) {
           // Display the error
           echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
       } else {
           // Display the result
           echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
           print_r($result);
       echo '</pre>';
       }
   }
   // Call the RectangleArea SOAP method
   $result = $client->call('RectangleArea', 
      array('L' => 40, 'l' => 20));

   // Check for a fault
   if ($client->fault) {
       echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
       print_r($result);
       echo '</pre>';
   } else {
       // Check for errors
       $err = $client->getError();
       if ($err) {
           // Display the error
           echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
       } else {
           // Display the result
           echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
           print_r($result);
       echo '</pre>';
       }
   }

    // Display the request and response
  /* echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
   echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, 
      ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
   echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
   echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, 
      ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';*/

//Call a function at server and send parameters too 
$response = $client->call('get_message',$param); 
//Process result 
if($client->fault) 
{ 
echo "<h2>FAULT:</h2> <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo $response; 
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Web Service SOAP and AJAX</title>           
     </head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxSOAP.js"></script> 
     <body>    
       <div style="position:relative;left:0px;
         top:-12px;background-color:#1D3968;margin:0px;">   
       <h2 align="center"><font color="#ffffff">
         Consume WebServices through SOAP-AJAX calls</font></h2></div>
       <table align="center" cellpading="0px" cellspacing="3px" 
         bordercolor="#000000" border="0" 
         style="position:relative;width:300px;height:200px;">
         <tr>   
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><h1>Rectangle Area</h1></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td valign="center"><font color="#cc0000" size="3">
             Insert value for l:</font></td>
           <td><input id="l_id" type="text"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><font color="#cc0000" size="3">Insert value for L:</font></td>
           <td><input id="L_id" type="text"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="Calculate Area" onclick="myAjax();"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div id="resultDiv"></div>
          </td>
         </tr> 
       </table>    
     </body>
   </html>
```

**ajaxSOAP.js** file contains

```
var xhrTimeout=100;

function myAjax(){
var l_var = document.getElementById("l_id").value;
var L_var = document.getElementById("L_id").value;

var soapMessage ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:mathwsdl"> <SOAP-ENV:Body><tns:RectangleArea xmlns:tns="urn:mathwsdl"><L xsi:type="xsd:int">'+L_var+'</L><l xsi:type="xsd:int">'+l_var+'</l></tns:RectangleArea></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

var url='http://localhost:81/WebServiceSOAP/server.php';
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
      httpRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
   }
   httpRequest.open("POST",url,true);
   if (httpRequest.overrideMimeType) { 
      httpRequest.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); 
   }
   httpRequest.onreadystatechange=callbackAjax;

   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Man","POST http://localhost:81/WebServiceSOAP/server.php HTTP/1.1")       

   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("MessageType", "CALL");

   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

   httpRequest.send(soapMessage);
}

   function callbackAjax(){
      try {
         if(httpRequest.readyState==4) {
            if(httpRequest.status==200) {
              clearTimeout(xhrTimeout);                                                             
              resultDiv=document.getElementById("resultDiv");            
              resultDiv.style.display='inline';                                          
              resultDiv.innerHTML='<font color="#cc0000" size="4"><b>'+httpRequest.responseText+'</b></font>';
            }
         } 
      } catch(e) { 
           alert("Error!"+e); 
      }      
   }
```

Comment: Thanxx a ton for this!!! I tried commenting the line
`httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Man","POST http://localhost:81/WebServiceSOAP/server.php HTTP/1.1")`

But this didn't make any difference. As in I was still able to get the response as usual. So what is the significance of this line? Thanxx